# Git push - git wants to merge but there are no changes in remote

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have a problem with git. Sometimes it makes me do *merge* to push, but recent changes are mine. The problem is that sometimes I have conflicts because the files I've modified previously are the same.

Has anyone have had this problem and know how to fix it?

Details: I have ubuntu 12.04 + eclipse kepler + egit 3.0 + git 1.7.9.5 .

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to the line endings. See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings.

Comment: Thank you! I've read your link, but i don't have to commit no modified files.
My problem is that i can't do push even when i have the last changes.

What's your point?

Comment: You did a fetch before push? Sure you are the latest who changed files?

Comment: Yes i did. If i go to github.com, i can see the last commits and the last commit is mine.

Comment: If i do "git status" console says me:
# On branch Beta_2800
# Your branch and 'origin/Beta_2800' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively

But i never make "git fetch"! How can git know that there are changes from remote (inexistent changes)?